# Why isn't the system() command working for me?

Tags: c

I'm new to c, so I'm probably stupid.

Here is somewhat my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int input;
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  printf("Welcome to example");
  printf("\n" "Select an option." "\n" "1. ex1" "\n" "2. ex2" "\n");
  scanf("%d", &input);
  if (input == 1) {
    printf ("You selected ex1.");
    system("echo 'testing.'");
  }
  else if (input == 2) {
    printf ("You selected ex2.");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you're wondering, I'm running the exe in MSYS2 with ./a.exe

If I input 1, then it should execute the command echo. However, it does nothing.

How do I fix this?

Edit: Heres the output

```
You selected ex1.
```

And then the program ends.
It could be because system uses command prompt (I'm having issues with command prompt...), so how do I switch it to use MSYS2 as the system terminal?

Comment: Your code works for me. When you "input 1", do you press the [enter] key?

Comment: Note that "works for me" means that the program prints its menu, I press the '1' key followed by the <enter> key, and the program responds by printing "You selected ex1.testing." followed by a newline, then exits.  That shows all your program's direct output, and also the output of the `echo` command.

Comment: When I run the program on MS Visual Studio 2017, I also get the output of `echo 'testing'.`. Have you tried running the program from the Windows command prompt?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I am having some issues with command prompt, plus I prefer MSYS2 anyway.

Comment: I think I'm just better off programming in shell...

Comment: I have now also tested the posted code in a very old version of MinGW/MSYS and it works there, too. However, I have not tested it with MSYS2, as I don't have it installed.